# How to add line types to a graph with multiple lines of different colours and is gathered on one key?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm trying to add different line types for the following graph:
[see this link for the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Hx0.png),

**The graph is created by the following code:**

```
#transformations
dtx[rec_type == 'recsemi', mlshare_recsemi := mlshare]
dtx[rec_type == 'recartist', mlshare_recartist := mlshare]
dtx[rec_type == 'recfully', mlshare_recfully := mlshare]

tmp = dtx[, list(mlshare=mean(mlshare,na.rm=T),
             Fully_personalized=mean(mlshare_recfully, na.rm=T),
             Semi_personalized=mean(mlshare_recsemi, na.rm=T),
             Artist_specific=mean(mlshare_recartist, na.rm=T)), by = c('date')]

tmp[, date:=as.Date(date)]
tmp <- tmp[date<as.Date('2020-04-15')]

plotdata <- tmp %>%
select(date, Fully_personalized, Semi_personalized, Artist_specific) %>%
gather(key = "rec_type", value = "mlshare", -date)
head(plotdata)

### major label share per recommendation type by date ###
p1 <- ggplot(data = plotdata, aes(x = date, y = mlshare)) + 
              geom_line(aes(color = rec_type), linetype = 1, size = 1.05) + 
              scale_color_manual(labels = c("artist-specific", "fully-personalized", "semi- personalized"),
              values = c("steelblue", "lightsteelblue", "dodgerblue")) +
              theme_bw() +
              #ggtitle("Major label share on recommendations, by recommendation type") +
              #theme(plot.title = element_text(size = (11), face = "bold", hjust = 0.5 )) +
              xlab("Date") +
              ylab("Major label share") +
              theme(axis.title = element_text(size = (9), face = "bold", hjust = 0.5 )) +
              scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", minor_breaks = "1 week", labels=date_format("%b %Y")) +  
              scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.450, 0.600)) +
              labs(color = "Recommendation") +
              theme(legend.position = "right", legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 10), 
              legend.text = element_text(size = 8.8, face = "italic"))
```

The created data registers the major label share (between 0-1) and has a row for the combination of every recommendation type and date within the panel data and looks like this:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════╦══╗
║         date           rec_type   mlshare ║  ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════════╬══╣
║ 1 2019-10-01 Fully_personalized 0.5044463 ║  ║
║ 2 2019-10-02 Fully_personalized 0.4985080 ║  ║
║ 3 2019-10-03 Fully_personalized 0.4975591 ║  ║
║ 4 2019-10-04 Fully_personalized 0.4985846 ║  ║
║ 5 2019-10-05 Fully_personalized 0.4990653 ║  ║
║ 6 2019-10-06 Fully_personalized 0.4970524 ║  ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════╩══╝
```

Now my question is how I add different line types to the existing graph with a matching legend. I've tried multiple options but ended up with multiple legend's because I only have one key. Not that experienced at using Stack Overflow, so if need any other information let me know! Formatting tips are also welcome :)

Let me know if you know any solution!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move `linetype` inside the `aes()` call and map it to a variable. If you map `linetype` to the same variable as `color`, you get one legend.

I don't have your name so here is an example with some made up data.

```
library(deplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(101)
expand.grid(year = 1990:2000, cat = LETTERS[1:4]) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(value = rnorm(1, mean = which(LETTERS == cat))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = value, color = cat, linetype = cat)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1990:2000))
```

[image]